# Creating multiple webgl textures in Chrome

Tags: javascript, linux, html, google-chrome, webgl

I have 2 models that I loaded, both with different textures. Things run perfectly on Firefox, I can apply both textures to each object. However, on Chrome, the second texture never shows up. I simplified my code a lot, and found that it probably has something to do with how I load my textures.

```
function texture() {
    this.texture = null;
}

texture.prototype.loadTexture = function(gl, img) {
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, this.texture);
    gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, img);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
}

texture.prototype.load = function(gl, name) {
    this.texture = gl.createTexture();
    var img = new Image();
    that = this;
    img.onload = function() {
        that.loadTexture(gl, img);
    } 
    img.src = name;
}
```

The way I create a new texture is:

```
var texture = new texture();
texture.load(gl, "foo.bar");
```

When I render each model separately, it renders them properly. The issue is when I use both models in the same scene. I don't have this issue with Firefox. I created an array of 2 textures using the above method, and forced both models to render the first texture. This works fine. However, when I render the second texture, nothing happens on Chrome, but it works on Firefox. Chrome actually does a lot of unpredictable things depending on which texture was loaded first, and which texture I force both models to use. In general, Chrome throws "RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable"

So this leads me to believe that there is something wrong in the way I am loading my textures. So my question is: is this the proper way to load textures? I got this from an online tutorial, and they only seem to use 1 texture/model at a time. I'm running Chromium for Linux, I haven't tested on Windows yet (if that helps).

Answer (score 1):

Upon some more research, I solved my problem. I used the load function from Mozilla's developer site:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebGL/Using_textures_in_WebGL

The only difference between this and my code is that the Mozilla version uses a function whereas I use an object (I also didn't mimmap my texture, but I don't think this is an issue).

So now I'm confused why this works, but my original implementation doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not generating mips then and you're not setting up your textures filtering not to need the mips then your textures SHOULD NOT RENDER. If they are it's a bug in the browser. The code you have above assumes mips exist. To turn off the need for mips set the texture wrapping to `CLAMP_TO_EDGE` and set the filtering to `NEAREST` or `LINEAR` (this part you were already doing)

```
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

Comment: Hmm it works in Chrome and Firefox without that, on Linux, Windows and Mac =S

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
that = this;
```

clobbers a global variable the second time you call it.

Comment: Ah I did not know that variables are created in the global space if you don't specify 'var'. Thanks!